# In data(aml) : data set ‘aml’ not found

Tags: r

```
library(readr)

aml <- read.csv("~/Documents/MH4315/aml.dat", sep="")
View(aml)

data(aml)
aml.km<-survfit(Surv(time,status)~x, data = aml)
plot(aml.km, main="Estimated survival function of the two
     groups", lty=c(1,2) )
```

When i run my code, it pops up an error that in `data(aml): data set 'aml' is not found`.
I am not sure what is wrong with my code. And so, is the code for my `aml.km` correct?

Comment: Use Projects to avoid this issue: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you expected from the `data(aml)` call. The `data` function is used to load data objects from installed packages. There is an `aml` dataset in both the survivla package and the boot package and I think they are identical, at least they have the same number of columns and rows as well as a similar description in their associated help pages. Since at the moment I do have the survival package loaded when I do this:

```
data(aml)
```

Nothing happens at the console but in this case no-news-is-good-news. The dataset is in the workspace.

You on the other hand have read in an `aml` data object from your local disk so we cannot really be sure what it has in it. When I run you survfit call I get no error:

```
 aml.km<-survfit(Surv(time,status)~x, data = aml)

> aml.km
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x, data = aml)

                 n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
x=Maintained    11      7     31      18      NA
x=Nonmaintained 12     11     23       8      NA
#----------------------
png();plot(aml.km); dev.off()
#RStudioGD
```

[image]